# Detect the presence of Bash completion in bash

Tags: bash, bash-completion

What is the way to detect if bash completion package is loaded in my bash shell? As of version 2.1 of `bash-completion` (included in Debian 8), there is no shell variable to indicate this except `BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR`, which is not a reliable indicator.

Comment: You have received several answers to your questions, yet have never accepted an answer as correct or helpful. You might want to evaluate them and where possible [accept them as correct or helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 9):

You can use [the `complete` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) with the `-p` option to get a list of all or specific completions. I'm not sure how reliable this would be either, given that you can load and unload them at will.

```
complete -p
```

One other option is to check for [one of the more unique function names](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L373) with [the `type` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source) and see if it's a function.

```
type -t _get_comp_words_by_ref
```

[This question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/900244/how-to-find-the-difference-between-bash-completion-rules-on-different-hosts) may also provide some insight.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to a directory that has both files and subdirectories.
2. Type `cd <TAB><TAB>` and look at the list of autocomplete results.

If the autocomplete results contain **directories only (no files)**, then Bash Completion is installed.

If the autocomplete results include **files**, then Bash Completion is not installed. (An example is if you try this in a Docker Ubuntu container).